# SQL Server 2019: Inlining UDFs in views

Tags: view, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2019, inlining

I want to test the new feature of SQL Server 2019 - inlining of UDF functions. It seems that it works well when I call the function in a simple SELECT. However, the inlining is not performed, if the function is contained in a view.

I have a simple scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEmployeeFullName](@id INT) RETURNS NVARCHAR(100) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret NVARCHAR(100);

    SELECT @ret = FirstName + ' ' + LastName
    FROM Employee
    WHERE EmployeeId = @id;

    RETURN @ret;
END
```

and a view calling this function:

```
CREATE VIEW QEmployee AS
SELECT EmployeeId, dbo.GetEmployeeFullName(EmployeeId) AS FullName, FirstName, LastName, Street, City, ZipCode, EMail, Phone
FROM Employee
```

If I run only the SELECT:

```
SELECT EmployeeId, dbo.GetEmployeeFullName(EmployeeId) AS FullName, FirstName, LastName, Street, City, ZipCode, EMail, Phone
FROM Employee
```

the function is inlined:

[image: Query plan of SELECT over the base table]

However, if I run a SELECT over the view:

```
SELECT * FROM QEmployee
```

the inlining is no longer done:

[image: Query plan of SELECT over the view]

I inserted 100k records in the table. The query processing time in the first case (when the inlining is done) is approx. 1s, while in the second case, it is over 3s. Can anyone explain me, why SQL Server does not inline the function in the second case? I expected that the query plans in both cases should be exactly the same.

Comment: Side note, the use of this scalar function seems redundant for the test you are doing. You are already selecting from `Employee` in the `FROM`, so getting a scalar function to then read from the table again seems "silly", when you could just put `FirstName + ' ' + LastName` in the `SELECT` definition of your `VIEW` and achieve the same thing.

Comment: It could also not do data access and just take `@first, @last` and perform the concatenation. In either case, this should be an inline TVF and not a scalar. Surely it is simplified to demonstrate the problem, not to be a model use case.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I know that the using of the scalar function in this case is not ideal. My question is why the query plans for the two SELECTs (one over the table and (redundant) call of function, and the other over the view) are different.